# 413 Error FULL HEAD Query URL too large Rally

Tags: rally

I am using app SDK 2.0.I have the following code to retrieve the tasks for first 100 Team Members of the project for a particular Iteration

```
                //getting the first 100 elements of the owners Array
                owners = Ext.Array.splice(owners,0,100);

                //Initial configuration of the filter object
                var ownerFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                    property: 'Owner.DisplayName',
                    operator:'=',
                    value: owners[0]
                });

                /*Creating the filter object to get all the tasks for 100 members in that project*/
                 Ext.Array.each(owners,function(member){
                 ownerFilter = ownerFilter.or(
                 Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter',{
                 property: 'Owner.DisplayName',
                 operator:'=',
                 value: member

                 }));
                 });

                //Iteration Filter for the Object
                var iterationFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                    property: 'Iteration.Name',
                    operator:'=',
                    value: 'Iteration 4.2'
                });

                var filter = ownerFilter.and(iterationFilter);

                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                type: 'Task',
                success: function(model) {
                    var taskStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: model,
                        fetch:true,
                        limit:Infinity,
                        pageSize:200,
                        filters:[filter],
                        autoLoad:true,
                        projectScopeDown:true,
                        listeners:{
                            load:function(store,data,success) {
                                Ext.Array.each(data, function(record){
                                   console.log(record.data);
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
```

This code is giving me a 413 error since the URL for the query is too large.The request URL has names of all 100 members of the project.How can I solve this problem ? Are there any efficient filtering options available?

Answer (score 0):

Team Membership is a tough attribute to filter Artifacts on, since it resides as an attribute on Users and is a collection that can't be used in Queries.

In this case you might be better off doing more of the filtering client-side. Since Team Membership "approximates" or associates to Projects, you may wish to start by filtering your Tasks on Project, i.e. (Project.Name = "My Project"). Then narrow things down client side by looping through and ensuring each Task is owned by a member of the Team in your owners collection.

Alternatively, you might look to do something like use Tags on your Tasks that mirror the Team Names. You could then filter your Tasks server side by doing a query such as:

(Tags.Name contains "My Team")

I know these aren't ideal options and probably not the answer you're looking for, but, they are some ideas to avoid having to build a massive username-based query.